# How to save uploaded .csv file into SQL Server Management database using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio

This is a sample of my code. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, with asp.net version 2.0, when the user clicks the import button, the csv file will be saved in the database. My code contains errors, and I do not know how to solve them, please help!

```
protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection (@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSeminar;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader("filepath");

    string line;
    while ((line = Sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        line = Sr.ReadLine();
    }

    const string SQL = "INSERT INTO [Guest] ([GuestName], [IC_Number], [EventName], [GuestID]) VALUES (@GuestName, @IC_Number, @EventName, @GuestID)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GuestName", Sr);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IC_Number", Sr);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventName", Sr);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GuestID", Sr);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();// 1,0 will determine whether line is inserted, upload has error...
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please help, cos I am very new with this type of coding, and I have to implement it a.s.a.p :(

Comment: What are the error you're experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your insert query must be in your while
2. `Sr` is not your parameter, but `line` which contains an array of your data. So it is probably `line[i]` that you must give to AddWithValue
3. You are assigning line = Sr.ReadLine() twice in your code, just do it in the `while`

So try something like this:

```
protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection (@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSeminar;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    con.Open();

    StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader("filepath");
    string line;
    string SQL = "INSERT INTO [Guest] ([GuestName], [IC_Number], [EventName], [GuestID]) VALUES (@GuestName, @IC_Number, @EventName, @GuestID)";
    while ((line = Sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GuestName", line[0]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IC_Number", line[1]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventName", line[2]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GuestID", line[3]);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();// 1,0 will determine whether line is inserted, upload has error...
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for posting the code,but when i implemented it in my project, it gave this error " Object reference not set to an instance of an object. NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code" What does this means? Sorry for my ignorance =/

Answer (score 0):

i have done something like this however it was xls files i needed to import but not much differentce really, here is the code i used

Protected Sub ButtonImport_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonImport.Click
        PanelView.Visible = False
        PanelUpload.Visible = False
        PanelImport.Visible = True
        LabelImport.Text = "" 'reset to blank

```
    Dim xConnstr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & (Server.MapPath("SiteTemplate.xls")) & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"

    ' create your excel connection object using the connection string
    Dim objXConn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(xConnstr)
    objXConn.Open()
    Dim objCommand As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [importsites$]", objXConn)




    'Creating the data reader
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
    reader = objCommand.ExecuteReader()

    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    While reader.Read()

        counter = counter + 1

        Dim siteID As Integer = 0
        Dim siteIWSref As String = Convert.ToString(reader("siteIWSref"))
        If siteIWSref = "" Then
            siteIWSref = "."
        End If
        Dim siteUPRN As String = Convert.ToString(reader("siteUPRN"))
        If siteUPRN = "" Then
            siteUPRN = "."
        End If
        Dim siteName As String = Convert.ToString(reader("siteName"))
        Dim siteAdd1 As String = Convert.ToString(reader("siteAdd1"))
        Dim siteAdd2 As String = Convert.ToString(reader("siteAdd2"))
        Dim siteAdd3 As String = Convert.ToString(reader("siteAdd3"))
        Dim sitePcode As String = Convert.ToString(reader("sitePcode"))
        Dim siteContact As String = Convert.ToString(reader("siteContact"))
        Dim siteContactPos As String = Convert.ToString(reader("siteContactPos"))
        Dim siteContactTel As String = Convert.ToString(reader("siteContactTel"))
        Dim siteDesc As String = Convert.ToString(reader("siteDesc"))
        Dim siteCompany As Integer = CInt(CompanyDD.SelectedValue)

        Dim siteOccupants As String = Convert.ToString(reader("siteOccupants"))

        Dim siteType As String = Convert.ToString(reader("siteType"))



        siteID = ImportIntotblSite(siteIWSref, siteUPRN, siteName, siteAdd1, siteAdd2, siteAdd3, sitePcode, siteContact, siteContactPos, siteContactTel, siteDesc, siteCompany, siteOccupants, siteType)

        LabelImport.Text &= siteID & siteIWSref & " " & siteUPRN & " " & siteName & " " & siteAdd1 & " " & siteAdd2 & " " & siteAdd3 & " " & " " & sitePcode & " " & siteContact & " " & siteContactPos & " " & siteContactTel & " " & siteDesc & " " & siteCompany & " " & siteOccupants & " " & " " & siteType & "<br>"


    End While
    reader.Close()
    objCommand.Dispose()
    objXConn.Close()

    btnBack.Enabled = True

    btnBack.Visible = True

    btnSave.Visible = True
    btnSave.Enabled = True

End Sub
Protected Function ImportIntotblSite(ByVal siteIWSref As String, ByVal siteUPRN As String, ByVal siteName As String, ByVal siteAdd1 As String, ByVal siteAdd2 As String, ByVal siteAdd3 As String, ByVal sitePcode As String, ByVal siteContact As String, ByVal siteContactPos As String, ByVal siteContactTel As String, ByVal siteDesc As String, ByVal siteCompany As Integer, ByVal siteOccupants As String, ByVal siteType As String) As Integer


    siteIWSref = Left(siteIWSref, 20)
    siteUPRN = Left(siteUPRN, 20)
    siteName = Left(siteName, 60)
    siteAdd1 = Left(siteAdd1, 50)
    siteAdd2 = Left(siteAdd2, 50)
    siteAdd3 = Left(siteAdd3, 50)
    sitePcode = Left(sitePcode, 10)
    siteContact = Left(siteContact, 35)
    siteContactPos = Left(siteContactPos, 35)
    siteContactTel = Left(siteContactTel, 20)
    siteDesc = Left(siteDesc, 220)
    siteOccupants = Left(siteOccupants, 120)
    siteType = Left(siteType, 35)


    Dim siteID As Integer = 0
    Try
        Dim SSAdapter As New importSitesDataSetTableAdapters.tblSiteTableAdapter
        Dim SSDataTable As importSitesDataSet.tblSiteDataTable = Nothing
        SSDataTable = SSAdapter.GetDataByNumbers(siteIWSref, siteName, siteCompany)
        If siteName = "" Then
            siteName = ""
        End If
        'see if the category already exists in the table, if not insert it
        If Not SSDataTable Is Nothing Then
            If siteName = "" Then
                LabelImport.Text = LabelImport.Text & _
                                    "<font color=red>ERROR: BLANK SITE NAME: ROW NOT IMPORTED : " & _
                                    "ID: " & siteID & _
                                   " Name: " & siteName & " " & siteCompany & ".</font><br>"

            ElseIf SSDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                If Not SSDataTable(0).siteID = Nothing Then
                    siteID = SSDataTable(0).siteID

                    LabelImport.Text = LabelImport.Text & _
                                               "<font color=blue> Recorded already exists : " & _
                                             "ID: " & siteID & _
                                            "Name: " & siteName & " " & siteCompany & ".</font><br>"
                End If
            End If
        End If


        If siteID = 0 And siteName <> "" Then
            siteID = Convert.ToInt32(SSAdapter.InsertQuery(siteIWSref, siteUPRN, siteName, siteAdd1, siteAdd2, siteAdd3, sitePcode, siteContact, siteContactPos, siteContactTel, siteDesc, siteCompany, siteOccupants, siteType))
            LabelImport.Text = LabelImport.Text & _
            "<font color=green> ROW SUCCESSFULLY IMPORTED: " & _
               " ID: " & siteID & _
               " Name: " & siteName & " " & siteCompany & ".</font><br>"
        End If


        Return siteID
        'SSAdapter.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        LabelImport.Text = LabelImport.Text & "<font color=red>" & ex.ToString & ".</font><br>"
        Return 0
    End Try

End Function


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'TableButtons.Visible = False
    'FileUploadExcel.Visible = False
    'PanelUpload.Visible = False
    btnYes.Visible = False
    btnNo.Visible = False
    btnBack.Enabled = False
    btnBack.Visible = False
    ButtonView.Enabled = False
    ButtonImport.Enabled = False
    btnSave.Visible = False
    btnSave.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

try this and let me know how you get on.

there is a brilliant example of how to upload information onto an sql server at:
http://www.shiningstar.net/aspnet_articles/DataSet/DataSetProject.aspx

i am aware its for excel however surely there cant be that much difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, like I said, I'm new to this, therefore, I do not know how to translate it to C# =/

Comment: try googling a VB to C# converter and test the code out that way

Comment: or try the link i have posted, i think they have test code in C# you can use that then change it as necessary :-)